# Groovy - 'no signature of method' error when calling method in main

Tags: groovy

I'm new to Groovy and I'm trying to fill a hash map with strain names and corresponding N50 values of bacteria obtained from a JSON-file. First, I want to fill the hash with the strain names as keys.

My method for doing so looks like this:

```
    def getStrains() {

            //create Slurper to get content from JSON file
            def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
            def inputFile = new File("-path to JSON file-")
            def inputJSON = slurper.parseText(inputFile.text)

            InputJSON.strains.each{

                //get strain names from JSON file
                def genus = it.genus
                def species = it.species
                def strain = it.strain
                def folderName = "${genus}_${species}_${strain}"

                //save folder name in hash
                n50Values[folderName]

            }
    }
```

Now when I want to call my method in my main method (just to see if the strain names are correct) like this

```
    public static void main (String[] args){
        getStrains() 
    }
```

I get the following Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static scaffolds.ReadJSON.getStrains() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I defined the hash in the beginning of my class.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I don't know what the error message wants to tell me. I've looked through other people having the same error but they are all very subjective. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

declare the getStrains()  as static since it is calling from a static context

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled your var name:

```
        def inputJSON = slurper.parseText(inputFile.text)

        **i**nputJSON.strains.each{
```

btw, this

```
n50Values[folderName]
```

doesn't make any sense. perhaps you want to have it like

```
 n50Values << folderName
```

or

```
 n50Values[folderName] = folderName
```

UPDATE:

looks like you want to use a collect instead of each here:

```
def n50Values = inputJSON.strains.collect{ 
  /*your code*/ 
  folderName 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't catch that. However, I'm now getting a different error: Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: n50Values for class: scaffolds.ReadJSON

Does that mean my method doesn't recognize my array?

Comment: the error means, that you have not defined the `n50Values` variable in your script. looks like you want to use a `collect` instead of `each` here...  `def n50Values = inputJSON.strains.collect{ /*your code*/ folderName }`